# Has anyone worked with using Pardot form integrated into Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried following the link below.

http://www.pardot.com/faqs/html-css/optimizing-forms-on-mobile-devices/

It says I can use the same CSS3 media queries from my Twitter Boostrap CSS/LESS stylesheets to Pardot's form stylesheets, under Layout template.

But when I attempted to write this media query up inside Layout Template.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
// some CSS code here from Boostrap
}
```

And then viewed it on my browser.  It doesn't work!

It's as if it could not detect my Bootstrap CSS3 stylesheets when the browser is rescaled on mobile devices due to its Pardot's internal iframe's setup.

Can somebody point out is the mobile responsive can be done with such integration?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to include a link to your Bootstrap stylesheet in the Pardot Form Layout Template.

Add https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer to get your iframes to be responsive and automatically resize vertically, which is really helpful when you have form errors or a form that grows or shrinks in height for confirmation or conditional fields.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <meta name="description" content="%%description%%"/>
            <title>%%title%%</title>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yourdomain.com/media/styles/bootstrap.min.css">

        </head>
        <body>
            %%content%%

            <!-- Use iframe resizer to allow this form to resize itself in the parent page -->
<script src="https://yourdomain.com/media/scripts/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely. Just add https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css before the close of your head tag and add the col-sm-6 for 2 column or col-sm-4 for 3 column layouts. Works beautifully. If you need to add a class to the submit button just go to the layout template and open the form tab. You can add the class there.